# Optimizing query for compressing tick price data into O-H-L-C intervals

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've been working on optimizing a query which compresses tick price data into O-H-L-C intervals. I'm trying to accomplish this with a single query, instead of having to use multiple queries with row partitioning to determine the Open and Close.

With the help of a great response to a question I posted yesterday, I've come up with this so far:

```
 DECLARE @Interval INT = 5
 DECLARE @InstrumentId INT = 36
 DECLARE @Start_Date DATETIME = '2015-01-01'
 DECLARE @End_Date DATETIME = '2015-03-30'
 DECLARE @OffsetTime DATETIME = 0

   SELECT INSTRUMENT_ID, 
         DATEADD(minute,(DATEDIFF(minute,@OffsetTime,[TIME_STAMP])/@Interval)*@Interval,@OffsetTime) INTERVAL_TIME,
         SUBSTRING(MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),[TIME_STAMP],21) + '_' + 
                       CAST(RATE_BID AS VARCHAR(10))),25,8)                                          [OPEN],
         MAX(RATE_BID)                                                                                HIGH, 
         MIN(RATE_BID)                                                                                LOW,  
         SUBSTRING(MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),[TIME_STAMP],21) + '_' +
                       CAST(RATE_BID AS VARCHAR(10))),25,8)                                          [CLOSE]
    FROM dbo.TICKS 
   WHERE INSTRUMENT_ID = @InstrumentId AND TIME_STAMP BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date
GROUP BY DATEADD(minute,(DATEDIFF(minute,@OffsetTime,[TIME_STAMP])/@Interval)*@Interval,@OffsetTime),    
         INSTRUMENT_ID
ORDER BY INTERVAL_TIME
```

Is there a more efficient way to concatenate the date/time to the price, then extract only the price once the MIN and MAX is evaluated?  I was thinking about a binary representation of the date/time , adding it to the price , then some bit operation to extract the price. I'm not quite sure where to begin.

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the performance of a query, it would be useful to have DDL and sample data. I am assuming the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE TICKS (
    INSTRUMENT_ID INT,
    TIME_STAMP DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (INSTRUMENT_ID, TIME_STAMP),
    RATE_BID INT NOT NULL
)
```

To generate some sample data, I used the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Numbers(@N int)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
WITH
L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS C UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS O), -- 2 rows
L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS C FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B), -- 4 rows
L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS C FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B), -- 16 rows
L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS C FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B), -- 256 rows
L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS C FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B), -- 65,536 rows
L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS C FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B), -- 4,294,967,296 rows
Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Number FROM L5)
SELECT Number FROM Nums WHERE Number<=@N

GO
--DELETE dbo.TICKS

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @INSTRUMENT_ID INT
SET @INSTRUMENT_ID=1

WHILE @INSTRUMENT_ID<50 BEGIN
    DECLARE RandomData CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT TIME_STAMP, CONVERT(INT,RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*10) AS Delta, 
        CONVERT(BIT,CONVERT(INT,RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*1.1)) AS ChangeDirection 
    FROM (
        --SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,Number,'20150101') AS TIME_STAMP FROM dbo.Numbers(150000)
        SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,Number*10,'20150101') AS TIME_STAMP FROM dbo.Numbers(900000)
    ) x
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,TIME_STAMP) BETWEEN 8 AND 15
    AND (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,TIME_STAMP)+@@DATEFIRST)%7>1
    AND TIME_STAMP>'20150103'

    OPEN RandomData
    DECLARE @TIME_STAMP DATETIME, @Delta INT, @ChangeDirection BIT

    DECLARE @RATE_BID INT, @Direction SMALLINT
    SET @RATE_BID=CONVERT(INT,RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*10000)+100
    SET @Direction=1

    WHILE 1=1 BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM RandomData INTO @TIME_STAMP, @Delta, @ChangeDirection
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 BREAK

        SET @Direction=CASE WHEN @ChangeDirection=1 THEN -@Direction ELSE @Direction END
        IF @RATE_BID<100 AND @Direction<0 SET @Direction=1

        SET @RATE_BID=@RATE_BID+@Delta*@Direction

        INSERT INTO dbo.TICKS VALUES (@INSTRUMENT_ID, @TIME_STAMP, @RATE_BID)
    END

    CLOSE RandomData
    DEALLOCATE RandomData

    SET @INSTRUMENT_ID=@INSTRUMENT_ID+1
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Then I tested your original query against a variation using binary data types instead of strings:

```
DECLARE @Interval INT = 5
DECLARE @InstrumentId INT = 36
DECLARE @Start_Date DATETIME = '2015-01-01'
DECLARE @End_Date DATETIME = '2015-03-30'
DECLARE @OffsetTime DATETIME = 0

DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
SET @StartTime=GETDATE()

  SELECT INSTRUMENT_ID, 
         DATEADD(minute,(DATEDIFF(minute,@OffsetTime,[TIME_STAMP])/@Interval)*@Interval,@OffsetTime) INTERVAL_TIME,
         SUBSTRING(MIN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),[TIME_STAMP],21) + '_' + 
                       CAST(RATE_BID AS VARCHAR(10))),25,8)                                          [OPEN],
         MAX(RATE_BID)                                                                                HIGH, 
         MIN(RATE_BID)                                                                                LOW,  
         SUBSTRING(MAX(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),[TIME_STAMP],21) + '_' +
                       CAST(RATE_BID AS VARCHAR(10))),25,8)                                          [CLOSE]
    FROM dbo.TICKS 
   WHERE INSTRUMENT_ID = @InstrumentId AND TIME_STAMP BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date
GROUP BY DATEADD(minute,(DATEDIFF(minute,@OffsetTime,[TIME_STAMP])/@Interval)*@Interval,@OffsetTime),    
         INSTRUMENT_ID
ORDER BY INTERVAL_TIME

PRINT CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,3),DATEDIFF(MS,@StartTime,GETDATE())/1000.)
SET @StartTime=GETDATE()

  SELECT INSTRUMENT_ID, 
         DATEADD(minute,(DATEDIFF(minute,@OffsetTime,[TIME_STAMP])/@Interval)*@Interval,@OffsetTime) INTERVAL_TIME,
         CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(MIN(CONVERT(BINARY(8),[TIME_STAMP]) + 
                       CAST(RATE_BID AS BINARY(4))),9,4))                                          [OPEN],
         MAX(RATE_BID)                                                                                HIGH, 
         MIN(RATE_BID)                                                                                LOW,  
         CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(MAX(CONVERT(BINARY(8),[TIME_STAMP]) + 
                       CAST(RATE_BID AS BINARY(4))),9,4))                                          [CLOSE]
    FROM dbo.TICKS 
   WHERE INSTRUMENT_ID = @InstrumentId AND TIME_STAMP BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date
GROUP BY DATEADD(minute,(DATEDIFF(minute,@OffsetTime,[TIME_STAMP])/@Interval)*@Interval,@OffsetTime),    
         INSTRUMENT_ID
ORDER BY INTERVAL_TIME

PRINT CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,3),DATEDIFF(MS,@StartTime,GETDATE())/1000.)
```

On my system, I the string version executes in 490ms, and the binary version in 293ms.